# exact definition of rate of convergence

Tags: convergence, definition

Can anyone concisely clarify within the framework of parametric regressions and sample size $N$ what is the rate of convergence? Increasing the exponent $k$ in $N^k$ (or $N^{-k}$) will increase or decrease this rate and why is this considered to be good (or bad)?

The reason why I am asking is that when googling "convergence rate" I find both sources that claim the rate to be $N^{0.5}$, while other sources claim it is $N^{-0.5}$. Both can't be right.

Comment: Intuitively I believe it should be the first one, as when we look at the asymptotic variance of an estimator, it degenerates by $1/N$, thus its square. From this standpoint it seems that a higher parameter k, increases the speed of its variance to degenerate and hence the estimators convergence in probability to its true parameter...

Comment: *What quantity* using *what statistical procedure* are you talking about here?  It matters!  Incidentally, "k" is no parameter--it is a property of the procedure.  The only way you can change it is by changing the procedure (or your assumptions about the data).

Comment: "Exponent" would work just fine.  The problem is that "parameter" has a more particular meaning in most statistical settings, so using that term could create confusion especially in the absence of any clear context.

Comment: I am talking about asymptotic properties and consistency in regressions.

Comment: I think I understand. You might be noticing a lack of convention or worse a bit of sloppiness, but in defense of your sources, observe that because $N^{0.5}$ *increases* without bound as $N$ grows, the person using that term to characterize a rate of convergence was at no risk of being misunderstood: they either meant that by some measure some series indexed by $N\to \infty$ was growing close to a limit at a rate of $1/N^{0.5}$; or possibly they might have been discussing a limit as $N\to 0$--but the use of "$N$" for such an index would be unconventional.

Comment: So given that I have the limit distribution of $\sqrt{N}(\hat\beta-\beta)$, the rate of convergence is $1/N^{0.5}$?

Comment: I mean, increasing the "rate", what does it mean truly? That the estimator converges faster to its parameter? Does this imply thus that the limit distribution must be multiplied by the inverse of this rate to be non-degenerate? Is that the answer?

Comment: I guess the confusing is, when k is increasing, the $1/N^k$ is decreasing, but we actually say the rate is increasing!! That's why calling $1/N^k$  to be the rate seems counter-intuitive and literature has picked up on $N^k$...